# How to add a day to a date in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to add 1 day to a date variable in TypeScript. May I know how can I add a day to a date field in TypeScript.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, please reopen. I need to specify a TypeScript answer. TypeScript has capabilities above and beyond JavaScript.

Comment: Using DefinitelyTyped definition for DateJS
    
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/datejs/datejs-tests.ts
    
// Add 1 days to Today
Date.today().add(1).days();

Answer (score 82):

This is just regular JavaScript, no need for TypeScript.

```
yourDate = new Date(yourDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
```

1000 milliseconds in a second * 60 seconds in a minute * 60 minutes in an hour * 24 hours.

Additionally you could increment the date:

```
yourDate.setDate(yourDate.getDate() + 1);
```

The neat thing about `setDate` is that if your date is out-of-range for the month, it will still correctly update the date (January 32 -> February 1).

See more documentation on [setDate on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate).

Answer (score 32):

```
 addDays(date: Date, days: number): Date {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
        return date;
    }
```

In your case days = 1

Comment: You might get 'date.getDate is not a function' when trying this.

Comment: check whether the date variable is string, the error is because of that, if yes then first convert it to a date and then pass it to the above function